# How do I iterate through Wordpress admin menu sub menus?

Tags: wordpress, loops, menu, submenu

I can iterate through the top level Wordpress menu items to change the name but I now need to iterate through the sub menu items of that menu. I know I can do it using exact values $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'New Label'; but it's for a plugin where the menu item may not be in the same position every time so that won't work.

I've got this code for the top level menus.

```
function _rename_top_level_menu( $original, $new ) {
        global $menu;

        foreach( $menu as $key => $value ) {
           if( $original === $value[0]) {
             $menu[$key][0] = $new;
           }
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [menu walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)?

> Although the Walker class has many uses, one of the most common usages by developers is outputting HTML for custom menus (usually ones that have been defined using the Appearance → Menus screen in the Administration Screens).

Comment: Thanks for the link @GMarco24. I'll give it a whirl when I get chance. Cheers